# Splitting strings of tuples of different lengths to columns in Pandas DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

| id | human_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ('apples', '2022-12-04', 'a5ted') |
| 2 | ('bananas', '2012-2-14') |
| 3 | ('2012-2-14', 'reda21', 'ss') |
| .. | .. |

I would like a "pythonic" way to have such output

| id | human_id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ('apples', '2022-12-04', 'a5ted') | apples | 2022-12-04 | a5ted |
| 2 | ('bananas', '2012-2-14') | bananas | 2022-12-04 | np.NaN |
| 3 | ('2012-2-14', 'reda21', 'ss') | 2012-2-14 | reda21 | ss |

```
import pandas as pd

df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = df.human_id.str
```

The code I have tried give me error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) Python

How can I split the values in tuple to be in columns?

Thank you.

Comment: It will always give an error if you try to unpack more values than there are. You can try doing it by iterating over each value and seeing if there are two values or three. And adding the rows to the column accordingly

Comment: I think iterating through rows is so memory-consuming, I guess there should be an easier "pythonic" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. It will just put None in places where it couldn't find the values. You can then append the df1 to df.

```
d = {'id': [1,2,3], 
     'human_id': ["('apples', '2022-12-04', 'a5ted')", 
                  "('bananas', '2012-2-14')",
                  "('2012-2-14', 'reda21', 'ss')"
                 ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list_human_id = tuple(list(df['human_id']))

newList = []
for val in listh:
    newList.append(eval(val))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(newList, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(df1)

Output


        col1        col2   col3
0     apples  2022-12-04  a5ted
1    bananas   2012-2-14   None
2  2012-2-14      reda21     ss
```

Comment: it gave me error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12704, 1), indices imply (12704, 3)

Comment: Is the error coming from trying to convert to list? Can you try converting to list

Comment: creating the list is not giving error

df..human_id.to_list() gave me

["(tuple1)" , "(tuple2)", "(...)"]

Comment: Ohh. Is your tuple in strings? Can you show how your list looks like?

Comment: ["('apples', '2022-12-03'. 'a5ted')",
 "('bananas', '2012-2-14')",
 "('2012-2-14', 'reda21', 'ss')",..]

Comment: Oh. You have strings, not tuples

Comment: @WilliamHolmes Please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much @Swapnil Chauhan Swapnil, it worked as expected!

Comment: Your welcome. Can you please update the question so that it reflects that the tuples are string. It will help someone else searching for a similar thing

Comment: Great idea, corrected @Swapnil, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.human_id.tolist(),index=df.index,columns=['a','b','c']))
```

Comment: I have tried it and it gave me

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12704, 1), indices imply (12704, 3)

After a small change to

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['human_id'], index=df.index, columns=['a','b','c', 'd'])) it didn't drop error, but rather NaN columns of a,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

column will create dynamic with length of tuple and using same dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

id = [1, 2, 3]
human_id = [('apples', '2022-12-04', 'a5ted')
            ,('bananas', '2012-2-14')
            , ('2012-2-14', 'reda21', 'ss')]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'human_id': human_id})

print("*"*20,'Dataframe',"*"*20)
print(df.to_string())

print()

print("*"*20,'Split Data',"*"*20)

row = 0

for x in df['human_id']:

    col = 1

    for xx in x:

        #df['col'+str(z)] = str(xx)

        name_column = 'col'+str(col)
        df.loc[df.index[row], name_column] = str(xx)

        col+=1

    row+=1

print(df.to_string())
```

[image]